# Prefix my input text box with an asterik when using the built-in form controls for my label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to prefix the label with a * and currently it is displaying the asterik and then a newline, then my label.

How can I get both the asterik and the label on the same line?
I can't modify the label that is generated from the m.Code model.  Is there a way to embed the * somehow using the label control?

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div style="color: red;">*</div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @for = "SortOrder" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `</div>` end tag down after the label.
Using a `<span>` instead of a `<div>` would also have no line break (assuming default styles)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div style="color: red;">
        *
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @for = "SortOrder" })
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
</div>
```

Depending on how the @Html.LabelFor gets rendered (inspect the resulting page source to see) it may be necessary to style the label container differently for this to work. Use a `display:inline` css to achieve that.

If you have the intention of "mandatory field" indicating asterisks, they're often seen on the far side of the labels.